# Moving off from MO

Tags: support, user-accounts

> How is  the account in MO closed ?

What I mean is if I want to permanently close my login ( and let others know) what do I do

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [this page in the FAQ](https://mathoverflow.net/help/deleting-account).

As for letting people know, I'm not sure what you mean about that. I suppose that you can buy commercial time on the next Super Bowl, or maybe just some public access network, and let people know. Maybe a bus ad...

Comment: Thanks! My account will be made anon as per FAQ